# How to rotate custom marker image on google map objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

Currently i am working an app like Uber iOS application. I Already integrated Google Maps SDK and I showed custom image for User current location also. Currently I am getting some Driver's Current location details(Ex: 100 Driver's) from server. I saved in one `NSArray` and I tried to display those **Lat & Long** on GoogleMaps by using following code:

```
for(int i=0;i<[latLongArr count];i++)
{
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[(NSDictionary *)[latLongArr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Latitude"] doubleValue], [[(NSDictionary *)[latLongArr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"Longitude"] doubleValue]);
    marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
    marker.title = @"Title";
    marker.snippet = @"Sub title";
    marker.map = self.gMapView;
}
```

But I am looking **UIDesign & Functionality** like this:

[image]

Can Any one help me out how can I show User Current location & Driver's list of Annotations
**(How to rotate custom marker image on google map)**

Comment: You mush have a server to update location of car Or You can get current location & target location, speed from server , after that get direction and motion simulator with the speed

Comment: Yes. I already update user & driver current location to Server.. My question is (How to rotate custom marker image on google map) . If User open the app those all Car images will be rotate 360 degrees on Google Maps ---> That's what i am looking

Comment: Create NSthreads for each driver and user as well. Then update their location depending upon the data coming from server with some condition check for instance, if location of driver is within the radius of user then show else skip. Best is to first write down some algorithm or seudo code for this before directly coding.

Comment: In server side i am getting only Lat & Long for Driver's --> My requirement is i want to show those list on Google Maps (Already i did that). But the one more future like Direction API---> Car is moving Horizontal but (Car symbol is showing some times Vertical/Reverse and etc) but it's not rotate custom marker image as per car direction

Comment: @MannamBrahmam.How u moving car direction(rotation) as user moves.

Comment: @Uma Madhavi, Please refer this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35618161/4720315

Comment: @MannamBrahmam.. Thank you for your response. I am working with swift.I am unable to move or rotate marker, everything works fine.

Comment: @Uma Madhavi, I used same code in Objective-C, it's working fine for me. But I don't have good knowledge on Swift. Try to convert, If not I will try to a sample demo.

Comment: @MannamBrahmam. Thank you..

Answer (score 7):

In directions API (apple or google map) have a list points. So , to calculate the angle between two points, you can:

```
func DegreeBearing(A:CLLocation,B:CLLocation)-> Double{
    var dlon = self.ToRad(degrees: B.coordinate.longitude - A.coordinate.longitude)
    let dPhi = log(tan(self.ToRad(degrees: B.coordinate.latitude) / 2 + M_PI / 4) / tan(self.ToRad(degrees: A.coordinate.latitude) / 2 + M_PI / 4))
    if  abs(dlon) > M_PI{
        dlon = (dlon > 0) ? (dlon - 2*M_PI) : (2*M_PI + dlon)
    }
    return self.ToBearing(radians: atan2(dlon, dPhi))
}

func ToRad(degrees:Double) -> Double{
    return degrees*(M_PI/180)
}

func ToBearing(radians:Double)-> Double{
    return (ToDegrees(radians: radians) + 360).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360)
}

func ToDegrees(radians:Double)->Double{
    return radians * 180 / M_PI
}
```

and set rotation for maker

```
maker.rotation = DegreeBearing(self.fromPoint, B: self.toPoint)
```

Updated ObjC Code below

```
-(double) DegreeBearing:(CLLocation*) A locationB: (CLLocation*)B{
    double dlon = [self ToRad:(B.coordinate.longitude - A.coordinate.longitude)];
    double dPhi = log(tan([self ToRad:(B.coordinate.latitude)] / 2 + M_PI / 4) / tan([self ToRad:(A.coordinate.latitude)] / 2 + M_PI / 4));
    if  (fabs(dlon) > M_PI){
        dlon = (dlon > 0) ? (dlon - 2*M_PI) : (2*M_PI + dlon);
    }
    return [self ToBearing:(atan2(dlon, dPhi))];
}

-(double) ToRad: (double)degrees{
    return degrees*(M_PI/180);
}

-(double) ToBearing:(double)radians{
    double degree = [self ToDegrees:radians];
    return degree+360% 360;
}

-(double) ToDegrees:(double)radians{
    return radians * 180 / M_PI;
}
```

Comment: ThanQ.  If you don't mine Can you please provide some sample code in Objective-c . Currently i don't know Swift

Comment: ThanQ for responding. Let me try to implement ---> If you don't mine if you have any better solution for this Please post here.. ThanQ  Nguyen Hoan

Comment: not able to call marker.rotation=degreebearing any solution ??

Comment: @BadalShah. Have u got marker rotation . Please guide me how to rotate map marker using google maps.

Comment: I didn't got solution till now. if you will get then tell me please .