# Can i rotate marker google maps like direction of the phone Swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I need to make a marker that can rotate automatically like the direction of the phone.
Please, can anyone help me to do this? I'm creating like Uber marker, so the marker should be a car.
Thank you

[This the link of the map that I try to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWjtF.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i try to create like Uber application, i need the marker to be like marker on Uber application

Comment: @BilalMaarbani, TimH's question is more like, what specific code have you tried?

Comment: do you mean what is the language i used to create this application ? if yes i write it by swift 4

Comment: There are already many solutions available on google, why didn't you search first. If you have any specific issue then ask.

Comment: @BilalMaarbani You are new, so first read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i was search too many but i didn't find my answer, i need to rotate the marker automatically like the direction of the user

Comment: i edit the post, please see the image link that i uploaded to post, thank you all guys

Comment: here is your solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48394319/custom-annotation-move-animation-ios-swift-like-ola-uber-app-mapkit-swift?rq=1

Comment: @dahiya_boy this is mapkit not google map api, thank you for helping me

Comment: please any one can help me ?

Comment: Have you really searched the internet? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36450526/rotate-gmsmarker-in-direction-at-which-user-facing .. This one mentions uber also in the question..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rotate GMSMarker in direction at which user facing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36450526/rotate-gmsmarker-in-direction-at-which-user-facing)

Comment: https://www.udemy.com/advanced-ios-firebae-build-an-uber-clone-app/ maybe this tutorial will help you but you need to buy.

Comment: @Skywalker thank you for your replying, yes i search too many on the internet, this link you implemented have no right answer , what can i do ?

Comment: @V_rohit thank you for your reply, i will check it thank you

Comment: Try the answers that have been upvoted.. Please research more about stackoverflow..

Comment: Right answers are not the only correct answers. Other answers may work just as well, or in some cases even better than the answer marked as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution by myself..

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {

    let direction = newHeading.magneticHeading
    let radians = -direction / 180.0 * .pi
    let angle = SupportFunc.radiansToDegress(radians: CGFloat(radians))

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        self.mapView.animate(toBearing: CLLocationDirection(-angle))
    }
}
static func radiansToDegress(radians: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return radians * 180 / CGFloat(Double.pi)
}
```

Comment: Hi Bilal what is SupportFunc.

Comment: SupportFunc is a base class. we call the static method using the class name.